# @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) Can not load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'

Tags: spring, junit, springjunit4classrunner

I hava this code ,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class JunitDemo {

    @Test
    public void testAssertArrayEquals() {

        byte[] expected = "trial".getBytes();
        byte[] actual = "trial".getBytes();

        Assert.assertArrayEquals("fail", expected, actual);
    }
}
```

and run the test, there are errors

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not load an
>   ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating
>   your test class with @ContextConfiguration.
>         at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:276)
>         at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
>         ... 28 more

then, i find a same Q with SO,the solution is

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class JunitDemo {

    @Resource
    private ApplicationContext ApplicationContext;

    @Test
    public void testAssertArrayEquals() {

        byte[] expected = "trial".getBytes();
        byte[] actual = "trial".getBytes();

        Assert.assertArrayEquals("fail", expected, actual);
    }
}
```

in fact，for this pojo, i do'nt need the xml config.
and i will get other error

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [/JunitDemo-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>             at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
>             ... 37 more

How to correctly run my program ？

Comment: do you have any `@Configuration` class in your app? or you use xml-based configuration?

Answer (score 1):

From the [@ContextConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) docs:

> @ContextConfiguration defines class-level metadata that is used to
>   determine how to load and configure an ApplicationContext for
>   integration tests.

Annotation itself has property `loader` and doc says:

> If not specified, the loader will be inherited from the first
>   superclass that is annotated with @ContextConfiguration and specifies
>   an explicit loader. If no class in the hierarchy specifies an explicit
>   loader, a default loader will be used instead.
>
> The default concrete implementation chosen at runtime.

So you can specify context [loader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html#loader--) directly with `loader` property. To navigate to direct configuration use `locations` for xml and `classes` for annotated class config.

In you case looks like spring chosen `GenericXmlContextLoader` for context loading, you don't specify location so  ApplicationConext will be loaded from "classpath:/com/example/<*your
_test_class_name*>-context.xml"

This is [good article](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/test-spring.xml"})
```

where the xml contains test context (in simplest case it's the same as application context) to load/autowire all dependencies