# Java, Spring, Junit : Autowiring fails in testing

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, junit

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am trying to write some test cases. Currently, I am autowiring my Service layer methods and annotating the main class with `@ImportResouce`. I also tried `@ContextConfiguration`, but then I get an NPE for tests. What am I doing wrong?
JUNIT : 4.1.2  - Present in POM with scope test
Spring-4.1.6  -- Present in POM

Code :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml",
        "classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml", "classpath*:WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml"})
@Ignore
public class TestingController {

    @Autowired
    protected PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    protected GroupAccountService groupAccountService;

    @Autowired
    protected GroupCanvasService groupCanvasService;

    @Autowired
    protected GroupSectionService groupSectionService;

    @Autowired
    protected GroupNotesService groupNotesService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    protected AuthenticationManager am;

    @After
    public void clear() {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }

    protected void login(String name, String password) {
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(am.authenticate(auth));
    }

}
```

AllTests :

```
public class AllTests extends TestingController {

    public static final String MAIL = "myemail@gmail.com";
    private Person person;
    private GroupAccount groupAccount;
    private GroupCanvas groupCanvas;
    private GroupSection groupSection;
    private GroupNotes groupNotes;


    @Test
    public void runTests() {
        this.person = TestUtils.createPerson(MAIL);
        int personId = this.personService.addPerson(this.person);
        assertTrue(this.personService.getPersonById(personId).getUsername().equals(MAIL));
        login(MAIL, "PASSWORD");
        Person loggedInUser = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
}
```

Error log :

```
Running tests.AllTests
16:51:17.817 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.w.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [tests.AllTests]
16:51:17.827 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.w.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
16:51:17.843 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.w.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4ddced80, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1534f01b, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@78e117e3, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@2ea227af, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@4386f16]
16:51:17.852 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4ddced80] to prepare test instance [tests.AllTests@1d119efb]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264) [surefire-junit4-2.17.jar:2.17]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.17.jar:2.17]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124) [surefire-junit4-2.17.jar:2.17]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200) [surefire-booter-2.17.jar:2.17]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153) [surefire-booter-2.17.jar:2.17]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) [surefire-booter-2.17.jar:2.17]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration or @ContextHierarchy.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:61) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.358 sec <<< FAILURE! - in tests.AllTests
runTests(tests.AllTests)  Time elapsed: 0.008 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration or @ContextHierarchy.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  AllTests.runTests » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Log : As the log is more than 30000 chars, uploading it to pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/bTegatqN)

Comment: Can the downvoter explain why was this question downvoted. Thank you.

Comment: Why it failed to load application context, see the reason or provide the full logs?

Comment: @Barath : Log attached to bottom of main post.

Answer (score 0):

Why your config class annotated with `@Ignore`?

It's because `@Ignore` annotation maybe.

Comment: I have added that to specify that this is a configuration class for testing. I tried removing it and running the test, still same. Thanks

Comment: And try removing '@WebAppConfiguration'. I'm afraid 'TestingController' not a configuration class.

Comment: Sorry, Still no luck. Can you check the log attached at bottom of main post. Thanks

Comment: This is my last try. Please try importing bean XMLs as 
 @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/xml1.xml", "xml2.xml"})'

Comment: When I do that, the autowiring doesn't work. Do you want the screenshot? Thanks

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42268594/8107578) might help. If not, let me see the screenshot.

Comment: I dont have any class which is like  a Main class or which loads ApplicationContext for passing to loader, it's all managed by the XML's. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@ImportResource`, use the following;

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:./test.properties")
```

and

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AnyApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

Comment: Which file is test.properties? And which class do I have to pass for ContextConfiguration? Thanks.

Comment: It's just an example. You can pass all you properties file there. AnyApplicationContextInitializer is your own class. Something that implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>  But it's optional and you can leave it empty

Comment: When I remove ImportResouce and add ContextConfiguration, I get autowired failed error. TestPropertySource didn't help either. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: I'd rethink you approach of inherited tests. Annotations markups is not inherited for many reasons. Mark you  AllTests class properly initialised as SpringBootTest and loading resources with @TestPropertySource